# INSERT XML DATA TO SQL FIELD

Tags: php, mysql, xml, codeigniter, xpath

I wrote a function to insert the `<IBAN></IBAN>` and from the XML to MySQL Database. I cannot figure out why, I cant insert the data from there to MySQL.
This is the code I wrote.

```
public function test2(){
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('C:\Users\Nihit\Desktop\test.xml') or die ("could not open xml file");
               // performing sql query

            // count xml nodes
        $node = $xml->xpath("//IBAN/text()");

        var_dump($node);
        $num = 0;

         $text = $xml->asXML();
         $sql = "INSERT INTO transfer_packet VALUES(null, null, 0, null, " . $node . " , null, '" . mysql_real_escape_string($text) . "', " . $num . ", 1, 0, NOW(), null);";

            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

            if (!$result){

                var_dump($result);
                $result = mysql_query("SHOW ERRORS;");
                var_dump($result);

                }else{

             echo 'SUCCESS';
             echo 'updating id...';

             $last_id = mysql_insert_id();


             $result = mysql_query("update transfer_packet set ORIG_ID = " . $last_id . " where ID = " . $last_id .";");
               }




    }
```

The code is written in codeigniter.

## Update (error received)

```
Severity: Notice Message : Array to string conversion FIlename : controllers/xmlconverter.php Line Number :368 Unknown column 'Array' in field list'
```

This is the xml file I used

```
fkl.fi/teemasivut/sepa/tekninen_dokumentaatio/Dokumentit/…
```

And of course database does not update with a new row.

Comment: What is your error output/current result?

Comment: Please link your XML output or put the output text here, so I can write your code from zero.

Comment: @DenizB. the error Severity: Notice
Message : Array to string conversion
FIlename : controllers/xmlconverter.php
Line Number :368
Unknown column 'Array' in field list'
this is the xml file I used https://www.fkl.fi/teemasivut/sepa/tekninen_dokumentaatio/Dokumentit/FI_camt_054_sample.xml.xml
And ofcourse database does not update with a new row.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 
the error Severity: Notice
Message : Array to string conversion
FIlename : controllers/xmlconverter.php
Line Number :368
Unknown column 'Array' in field list'
this is the xml file I used https://www.fkl.fi/teemasivut/sepa/tekninen_dokumentaatio/Dokumentit/FI_camt_054_sample.xml.xml
And ofcourse database does not update with a new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [this](https://www.fkl.fi/teemasivut/sepa/tekninen_dokumentaatio/Dokumentit/FI_camt_054_sample.xml.xml) sample XML, you should use this code:

```
$xml        =   simplexml_load_file('https://www.fkl.fi/teemasivut/sepa/tekninen_dokumentaatio/Dokumentit/FI_camt_054_sample.xml.xml'); // get XML output

$xmlFile    =   file_get_contents('https://www.fkl.fi/teemasivut/sepa/tekninen_dokumentaatio/Dokumentit/FI_camt_054_sample.xml.xml'); // get XML output as text

$IBAN       =   $xml -> BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn -> Ntfctn -> Acct -> Id -> IBAN; // get IBAN value
$BIC        =   $xml -> BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn -> Ntfctn -> Acct -> Svcr -> FinInstnId -> BIC; // get BIC value

$transferDateTimestamp  =   strtotime($xml -> BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn -> Ntfctn -> CreDtTm); // Get transfer date as timestamp for transferred_date column
$data = array
(
'IBAN'              => $IBAN,
'BIC'               => $BIC,
'INSERT_DT'         =>  time(),
'xml_file'          => $xmlFile,
'status'            =>  '1',
'transferred_date'  =>  $transferDateTimestamp
);
$this -> db -> insert('tableName', $data); // inserting a new row to our table

$id = $this -> db -> insert_id(); // get last inserted id

$uptArray   =   array('ORIG_ID' => $id);
$this -> db -> where('id', $id);
$this -> db -> update('tableName', $uptArray); // updating ORIG_ID column
```

Comment: I actually want to get the xml file from the desktop, instead of the url. And which part do I delete and insert your code ?

Comment: I just changed my code, just use this you'll see the result. If you want to use a local XML output, you should change `'https://www.fkl.fi/teemasivut/sepa/tekninen_dokumentaatio/Dokumentit/FI_camt_054_sample.xml.xml'` part on first line.

Comment: I am using your code, but the other columns are not updating to how I want. Since I have more columns, as ID, type , total_amount, transferred_date , IBAN, BIC, xml_file, number_of_xml_structures, status =1, ORIG_ID = ID , INSERT_DT = NOW() , UPDATE_DT, so those columns are not being updated.

Comment: Ok than give me all details, what is your column names and which xml tag will send which column?

Comment: Also tell me, do you want to insert a new row or update an existing column?

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qquywed4l8cnvdk/transfer_packet%20table.PNG?dl=0)
@Deniz B.
That is a picture to the table.
I need to generate a new row, with a new generated ID, the xml_file should contain the XML file as a text, and ORIG_ID should be equal to ID , and status should be equal to 1 , and INSERT_DT should get a timestamp. The IBAN should come from the XML file and if you could help me get the BIC from XML file as well it would be really helpful, Thanks for your help

Comment: did you get my previous message?

Comment: did you get the screenshot?

Comment: I get it buddy, take it easy I'm checking.

Comment: Code is working good for me, please check your database structure. id field should be primary key. Check http://i.hizliresim.com/481lG4.png and http://i.hizliresim.com/EprJP8.png

Comment: do you think in the data array, all the column names should be present ???
$data = array
(
 'type' =>'null',
 'total_amount' => '',
 'number_of_xml_structures' => 'null',
'IBAN'              => $IBAN,
'BIC'               => $BIC,
'INSERT_DT'         =>  time(),
'xml_file'          => $xmlFile,
'status'            =>  '1',
 'UPDATE_DT'        => 'null',
'transferred_date'  =>  $transferDateTimestamp
);

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You have to add all data which you want to insert on that array.

Comment: B , Yes that's what I meant, right now I still get this error 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7sx2q3m8haypb5m/error%204.PNG?dl=0
even after I wrote the code like this `$data = array
(
 'type' =>'Remittance',
 'total_amount' => '0',
 'number_of_xml_structures' => '0',
'IBAN'              => $IBAN,
'BIC'               => $BIC,
'INSERT_DT'         =>  time(),
'xml_file'          => $xmlFile,
'status'            =>  '1',
 'UPDATE_DT'        => '0',
'transferred_date'  =>  $transferDateTimestamp
);`
but when I write the insert statement in MySQL , in IBAN if I put 'FI23445334' it works.

Comment: I don't know. I'm just sure that my code is right and working properly.

Comment: In the $IBAN part it says, SimpleXMLElement object {
0=> (string) FI3247832436478}
so it means I have to change the IBAN to string somehow, do you know a way ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to change it to string, as I said I tested it and worked good for me but if you want you can try this structure: string($IBAN)